# How do I create a Windows Service using vb.net in Studio 2008 Standard (No template)

Tags: vb.net, service

I want to create a Windows Service using VB.Net, but in VS2008 Standard, you don't seem to get the "Windows Service" template I've used before.

What's the best way of creating such a service, without resorting to using the C++ template?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing really special about the Windows Service template. It creates two class files in your project and adds a reference to `System.ServiceProcess`:

Service1.vb:

```
Public Class Service1

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        '' Add code here to start your service. This method should set things
        '' in motion so your service can do its work.
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnStop()
        '' Add code here to perform any tear-down necessary to stop your service.
    End Sub

End Class
```

Service1.Designer.vb:

```
Imports System.ServiceProcess

<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Service1
    Inherits System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

    ''UserService overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
        Try
            If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
                components.Dispose()
            End If
        Finally
            MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
        End Try
    End Sub

    '' The main entry point for the process
    <MTAThread()> _
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim ServicesToRun() As System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase

        '' More than one NT Service may run within the same process. To add
        '' another service to this process, change the following line to
        '' create a second service object. For example,
        ''
        ''   ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase () {New Service1, New MySecondUserService}
        ''
        ServicesToRun = New System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase() {New Service1}

        System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun)
    End Sub

    ''Required by the Component Designer
    Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

    '' NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Component Designer
    '' It can be modified using the Component Designer.  
    '' Do not modify it using the code editor.
    <System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
    Private Sub InitializeComponent()
        components = New System.ComponentModel.Container()
        Me.ServiceName = "Service1"
    End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class that inherits from System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase, override OnStart and OnStop.  Use installutil to register the service on your machine.